# How to navigate forward and backwards in folder structure several directories at a time

Tags: linux, shell

I'm in an Ubuntu 20.04 shell and I've mounted my Windows `C:\` to it.

**Target folder "structure":**

`/mnt/c/Users/Michael/Folders/Projects/GitremoteConnections/Issues/Conflicts/Week1`

**Question**

If I'm currently at `mick@msi:/mnt/c` is there a quick way of getting myself to the Week1 folder in one simple command?

**What I've tried**

I've tried `mick@msi:/mnt/c cd ~/Week1` ...but it doesn't work.

I could have sworn this used to work. I am obviously pretty new to Linux.

Comment: `~/` is short for your home directory. Try the `pwd` command, this will show your current directory.

Comment: So in other words your attempt would work if your `HOME` is `/mnt/c/Users/Michael/Folders/Projects/GitremoteConnections/Issues/Conflicts` but it's quite likely not, and absolutely should not be.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for `CDPATH`? This is a variable which is used in Bash when you `cd`, somewhat similarly to how `PATH` is searched when you try to run a command - if you try to `cd` to a directory which is not present, Bash will search through `CDPATH` and try to find a directory with a matching name in the listed directories.

(This requires you to say `cd Week1` and to have `/mnt/c/Users/Michael/Folders/Projects/GitremoteConnections/Issues/Conflicts/` as one of the entries in your `CDPATH`, obviously.)

See also [the `cd` documentation in the Bash Reference Manual.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-cd)

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd "/path/Different Directory/"
#do something
popd
```

Or use Midnight Commander which allows to handle file/directory operations a ton easier.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your super speedy reply Artem but I'm afraid it might be a little too advanced for me at this stage....unless you could expand somewhat on your comments. but.......is it not possible to move forward several directories at a  time using cd then?

Comment: This will work only for fast switching between the current dir and the other dir. If you need to juggle with more than two, I've no idea :-)

Comment: you can pushd many dirs, and once they are in the "list" just use `pushd +2` to change the one in second place. use `dirs`  to see the list.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot guys, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can add the path to the environment.

I use similar approach to move fast on a frequently accessed path.

In my `.bashrc` on my personal server there are something similar to :

```
SAMBA_NAS="/path/to/the/nas"
SAMBA_HOME="/path/to/the/remotehome"
```

So when i need to go to these directory i will do something such as:

```
cd $SAMBA_NAS
```

So you can add something similar to your `.bashrc`:

```
PROJECT_WEEK_1="/mnt/c/Users/Michael/Folders/Projects/GitremoteConnections/Issues/Conflicts/Week1"
```

And when you need to `cd'ing` to that path:

```
cd $PROJECT_WEEK_1
```

Of course : `PROJECT_WEEK` is just a placeholder, chose an appropriate one.